# c# .net core difference in date format MMM on Windows and Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, date-format

I've run into an issue. I need to parse Date in specific format ddMMMyy in cyrillic. When I run .net core application on Windows, date
**08АПР19**
correctly being parsed into 2019-04-08
but it throws exception when I parse it on Linux server
Exception: String '08АПР19' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The code causes exception is following:

```cs
DateTime.ParseExact(myDateVar, "ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"));
```

Then I tried to output the following on Windows and Linux:

```cs
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"))
```

the output on Windows:
**08апр19**

and Linux:
**08Апр.19**
There is an odd dot on Linux

In my understanding format hardcoded in .net framework and I wonder why it is platform-dependent. So the question is whay there is a difference on Win and Linux machines and who causes this problem?

Comment: Which OS/.NET version? It could be what the *OS* returns for this culture, or a .NET Core CultureInfo issue that may be fixed

Comment: It is .net core 2.1 on CentOS 7

Comment: I am seeing similar issues on Core 3.1 with Debian and el-GR culture. AM/PM designators are different in windows than in linux.

Comment: Has this been reported to the dotnet core project team?

Comment: I just reported it: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7599

Answer (score -1):

When you call a Function or Method of any namespace in .NET Framework (Same with Core) which is connected with the Operating System, .NET Framework calls the API functions of the Operating System. Then .NET gets some value returned by the Operating System and returns it to you. For this reason in different Operating Systems you will get different results.

For Example, Suppose GetProccessorType() (just example) is a DLL Function of WIndows OS and get_cpu_type() (just example) is the same function for Linux. Both of them returns the processor type. But suppose that GetProcessorType returns 0 if the CPU is 32 bit and 1 if the CPU is 64 bit. But in Linux the get_cpu_type returns 32 if it is 32 bit and 64 if it is 64 bit.

Now Suppose .NET Framework has a function GetCPUMode() (actually .NET Framework doesn't have it, just example) both in Linux and Windows(you should know it already).

When you call the function in windows

```
....
public static void Main(){
    Console.WriteLine(GetCPUMode());
}
....
```

Then if your PC is 64 bit then 1 will be shown as output in Windows and 64 as output in Linux. I think you will have to make a secondary parsing method to remove the dot. You can look at string manipulation methods for this purpose.

Comment: I understand this logic, but I also tried 'date' command and the output was without extra dot, so it doesn't seem to bu Linux format and still looks strange to me

Comment: Very mysterious

Comment: Try importing Microsoft.VisualBasic Namespace then call Replace(str, "Amp.", "amp"). This will return the string with dot removed

Comment: This is not an operating system issue. This is happening running the same code on the same windows box using two different targetframeworks: net4.8 and net6.0.